# How can i render a file using a formatter programmatically in a controller?

Tags: 8, files, page-controller

I'm trying to create a controller to render a swagger documentation using the module [swagger_ui_formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/swagger_ui_formatter) that provide a formatter to the file field that render swagger files (yml, yaml, json) using javascript libraries to show the documentation like swagger website do. Then i copy my yml file in my module directory and in my controller i can load this file.

```
  public function buildApiDocumentation() {

    $file_system = \Drupal::service('file_system');

    $searchFiles = '/^.*\.(yml)$/';
    $directory = dirname(__DIR__,2).'/docs';

    $file = $file_system->scanDirectory($directory, $searchFiles, ['recurse' => FALSE]);
}
```

But i don't know how can i render this file using the swagger formatter that the module provide, i can't use the traditional way to use this formatter, creating a content type with a file field and after that create a view and render it, because is a very manual process and i need to fix the api documentation file in a directory that only the dev team can update.

Comment: Why can't you return a render array with a custom theme function to do what you want?

Comment: A field formatter is used to render an entity field. Without an entity that is rendered, a field formatter cannot be used.

Comment: @apaderno interesting... i don't know that, so i need to create a node with this file and using this node i can render because now is an entity, right?

Comment: That's the only way to use a field formatter.

Answer (score 0):

You can return a [BinaryFileRespose](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21http-foundation%21BinaryFileResponse.php/class/BinaryFileResponse/9.2.x) from your controller:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse;

public function buildApiDocumentation() {

  $file_system = \Drupal::service('file_system');

  $searchFiles = '/^.*\.(yml)$/';
  $directory = dirname(__DIR__,2).'/docs';

  $file = $file_system->scanDirectory($directory, $searchFiles, ['recurse' => FALSE]);

  return new BinaryFileResponse($file);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what i'm looking for is how can i use a formatter to render this file, using the formatter that swagger_ui_formatter module provide. i need to render a yml like swagger website do.

Comment: I don't know this module, but if it has a field formatter, it means the data can be saved into a field. You need to create a field of that type, save the value to that field, and set that field to render output using that field formatter.

Comment: Thanks @jaypan i'm going to try this creating a node programmatically, set the file and after render it.

Answer (score 0):

as @apaderno mentioned we can't use a formatter that way, then i decided to build my own module to render my swagger documentation using the [official swagger ui](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui), and load the file using a javascript directive.

Thanks for helping.